# Redirect from www.mydomain.com/foo to www.mydomain.com/foo/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a piece of code in .htaccess file that:
replace php extension with trailing slash.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.cgi -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.cgi [L]

## redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.cgi -f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My question is how can I redirect all requests from  `www.mydomain.com/foo` to `www.mydomain.com/foo/`? (Notice the trailing slash)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Source & explanation: http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` no redirect if file exists
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$` Condition: "If no trailing slash"
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]` Redirect
  to URL + trailing slash